# django form template does not update

Tags: django, forms, templates

I have created a form and I POST selection with an action to go to specific url. Although, once directed the template does not update.

I need to hit Enter again and then obviously my request is lost so I get exception value `get_context_data() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

any ideas why ?

Below is my code and print screen of the problem.

**url**

```
url(r'^all_rooms/$', views.AllRoomsView.as_view(), name='roomsdetails'),
```

**template**

```
<form action="/blocks/all_rooms/" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}

<ul>
{% for choice in form.my_choice_field.field.choices %}
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="my_choice_field" value="{{choice.0}}"
      {% ifequal form.my_choice_field.data choice.0 %}
         checked="checked"
      {% endifequal %}/>
    <label for="">{{choice.1}}</label>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

EDIT:

Below is my AllRoomsView class. I suspect this is the class where the problem is.

```
class AllRoomsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'prostats/roomsdetail.html'
    queryset = Room.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllRoomsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['rooms'] = Room.objects.all()
        context['rlog'] = RoomLog.objects.all()

        roomsdates = []

        for r in context['rlog']:
            if r not in roomsdates:
                roomsdates.append(r.update_date)

        roomextracted = []
        for i in roomsdates:
            if i not in roomextracted:
                roomextracted.append(i)

        context['roomextracted'] = roomextracted

        choosend = '2016-02-16'
        context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__lte = choosend)

        return context
```

Comment: What does that `room_choices` view have to do with anything?

Comment: "I have created a form" so I show the view in which I have a function that calls the form.

Comment: Well now you've confused me even more. What exactly are you expecting to change? What exactly do you see instead of what you were expecting?

Comment: I see blank page with url 'http://localhost:8000/blocks/all_rooms/' however I should see roomsdetail.html with its context. This is what I see if I remove 'request' from def get_context_data

Comment: Right, because get_context_data does not take the request. Why did you put it in? What was the point of posting the form and the first view, since this question appears to have nothing at all to do with it?

Comment: ok, I have removed the view and the form. I will read about 'get_context_data' and work out how to pass request data into AllRoomsView class